# compare array of objects and remove specific item

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

```
arr1 = [
    {
        name: "will",
        value: "1"
    },
    {
        name: "nelson",
        value: "3"
    }
];
```

and

```
arr2 = [
    {
        name: "will",
        value: 1,
        submenu: [
            {
                name: "ralph",
                value: 2    
            }
        ]
        }
]
```

then remove ralph from the second array. i already created a function who do it but just check the first element and not verify the submenu.

```
comparador(arrSecundario) {
    return (arrAtual) => {
      return arrSecundario.filter(function (other) {
        return other.value === arrAtual.value;
      }).length !== 0;
    };
  }

this.arr2.filter(this.comparador(this.arr1));
```

Comment: looks like this might could use some recursion. also it would help if you had a working example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Based on which similar keys/values of `arra1` and `arr2` you want to remove

Comment: both arrays has the same properties, i need to remove the property that not match

Answer (score 0):

Need to map array after filter. You can do like this and can also add "prop === 'submenu'" for specifically checking submenu inner array only.

```js
var arr1 = [
  {
    name: "will",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "nelson",
    value: "3"
  }
];

var arr2 = [
  {
    name: "will",
    value: 1,
    submenu: [
        {
          name: "ralph",
          value: 2    
        },
        // {
        //   name: "nelson",
        //   value: 3
        // }
    ]
  }
];

function filterComparador(arrSecundario) {
  return (arrAtual) => {
    return arrSecundario.filter((other) => {
      return other.value == arrAtual.value;
    }).length != 0;
  };
}

function mapComparador(arrSecundario) {
  return (arrAtual) => {
    Object.keys(arrAtual).forEach((prop) => {
       if (Array.isArray(arrAtual[prop])) {
          let propValue =  arrAtual[prop].filter(this.filterComparador(arrSecundario));
          if (propValue.length > 0) {
            arrAtual[prop] = propValue.map(this.mapComparador(this.arrSecundario));
          } else {
            delete arrAtual[prop]; 
          }           
       }
    });
    return arrAtual;
  };
}

var manipulatedArray = this.arr2.filter(this.filterComparador(this.arr1))
    .map(this.mapComparador(this.arr1));

console.log(manipulatedArray);
```